# External HDD not appearing in windows explorer

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1

My Toshiba 2TB external HDD was working fine for about 1 year when it suddenly disappeared in file explorer. It is also not listed on Disk Manager and using different USB 3.0 ports don't solve the problem. However, when it is plugged in, a blue light appears for a few seconds before disappearing, additionally, the HDD is vibrating slightly when held in the hand, thus it must not have failed.

UPDATE: A possible explanation is that the computer does not have a PSU with a high enough output to properly use the external hard drive at times. (Under load for example.)

Comment: Just because its not vibrating doesn't mean it hasn't failed. Listen for a clicking noise.

Comment: Just a slight humming sound.

Comment: I would try another wire if you have one or borrow one from someone/buy another (should be cheap).  Also, have you tried plugging it into a different machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if the drive appears in BIOS? If it's not, then the PC itself couldn't recognize it, so the best option you have if that's the case is to try the basic troubleshooting steps:

1. Try a different USB cable since the issue could be related to that.
2. Plug the drive in another USB port. I see you've tried it, but give it a shot again, just in case, and if possible try the ports on the back of your PC.
3. Lastly, if none of the above fixes the issue, test the drive on another PC - this is will be the best way to make sure if the problem is related to the external or the computer somehow.

If the drive is recognized in BIOS though, then you can try to boot with Linux Live CD and try to access the information on that way. In order to do so you can follow these steps:

1. Download/burn the ISO image to a CD or USB.
2. Change the boot order to
   the media you burned the Linux on.
3. Once it loads, you could try and
   mount the drive (or if Linux can read it, it will mount by itself)
   and see if it shows up. In case it is - transfer the data.

If you want you can take a look at this Ubuntu KB article about Live CDas well:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Live

Hope this helps and let me know how it went! :)

Comment: The external HDD worked well this morning when I booted the PC...somehow. But your answer was still very helpful.